# Get innerHTML from Div into mvc Model

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I work on a mvc website, and i have a div with a contenteditable flag, so it's a big input field ( i can't change that ! ).

The DIV look's like that :

```
    <div id="email-text" contenteditable="true">
           Here is the Editable Text which i want to get 
    </div >
```

Now i want to get the Text from the DIV into my model but i found no way to get it.

I also don't know which keywords would be helpful for that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get innerHtml of email-text via Jquery or javascript before form submit and put it into a input.

```
<form id="myForm">  
    <input type="hidden" name="Text" id="emailTextInput" />
    <div id="email-text" contenteditable="true">
           Here is the Editable Text which i want to get 
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="btn" />
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").on("click",function(){
            var emailText = $("#email-text").html();
            $("#emailTextInput").val(emailText);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And in server side you need a View Model like following Model

```
public class EmailModel
{
    public string Text{ get; set; }
}
```

In Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(EmailModel emailModel)
{
   ...
}
```

When you click submit button jquery click event will raised and all text in Div Inner Html will copy to Hidden input.